# Workbox js is not caching when used in Electron

Tags: electron, workbox

workbox.js is not caching anything in Electron.

I am trying to integrate a PWA using a workbox.js service worker into Electron.

Everything works fine in Chrome and my service worker is able to register successfully in Electron. However nothing is cached inside Electron Application Cache.

My expectation would be that Workbox.js caches requests the same way it does in Chrome.

[Working in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp0M3.png)

[Registered in Electron but Nothing is in application Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAL9Z.png)